# Json.simple ошибка получения значения из JSON файла

Tags: java, json, парсер

Пишу код, возникла ошибка:

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(AppealRank(0.9f, "Silver"));
    }
    static Object DKFORR;{
        try {DKFORR = new JSONParser().parse(new FileReader("KDForRanks.json"));} catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();} catch (ParseException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
    static JSONObject KDForRank = (JSONObject) DKFORR;

    static final String[] Ranks = {"Stone", "Iron", "Bronze", "Silver", "Gold", "Platinum", "Diamond", "Immortal"};

    static Object AppealRank(float KD, String Rank){

        int RankIndex = Arrays.asList(Ranks).indexOf(Rank);
        float NeedbleKD = 0f;
        if(Rank == Ranks[Ranks.length - 1]){
            NeedbleKD = (float) KDForRank.get(Ranks[RankIndex]);
        }else{
            NeedbleKD = (float) KDForRank.get(Ranks[RankIndex + 1]);
        }

        if(KD >= NeedbleKD){
            if(KD >= (float) KDForRank.get(Ranks[Ranks.length - 1])){
                return Ranks[RankIndex];
            }else{
                return Ranks[RankIndex + 1];
            }
        }else {
            if (KD < (float) KDForRank.get(Rank)) {
                return Ranks[RankIndex - 1];
            } else {
                return Ranks[RankIndex];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а путь и имя файла точно правильно указаны?

Comment: Дмитрий, когда я навожу на название файла в коде он мне показывает его путь, где именно он лежит, фаил заполненный

Comment: вопос в том, что все ваши "наводки" - результат работы сторонних инструментов (вроде среды разработки). и это все здорово пока все работает. в вашем случае в тексте ошибки виднеется гордый null. самый "дубовый" способ проверить, находит ли ваш код файл, написать что-то в духе System.out.println(new File("KDForRanks.json").exists()); и посмотреть, будет ли в консоли true. это по крайней мере гарантирует, что такой файл дествительно найдет и читается. вторым шагом я бы проверил корреткность самого json любыми онлайн инструментами.

Comment: Дмитрий, пишет false, фаил лежит вместе с классом в одной папке

Comment: а почему он лежит вместе с классом в одной папке??? это папка для исходного кода, а не для всякого мусора. переместите в корневой каталог проекта и будет вам счастье

Comment: Спасибо вам за помощь <3